# Word to describe someone who fears the strong but bullies the weak

Tags: single-word-requests

A person who shows respect towards or fears those who are strong, aggressive, always ready to fight when pushed around or something unfair happens to them, but bullies the weak or those who dare not speak for themselves or fight back when treated unfairly or badly. What do we call this kind of people? Is there one word (adjective or noun) for that?

Comment: The only expressions that fit the bill to tee are vulgar ones.

Comment: A good phrase to describe the behaviour or strategy of a person like this in the workplace is ***kiss up, kick down***.

Comment: That's your classical bully.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure the best, non-vulgar word for a person like that is already found in your question:

- *bully*

A few other words you could use that fit the bully aspect:

- *Oppressor*
- *Tyrant*
- *Despot*

A few words that fit your first qualification for the word:

- *Craven*
- *Coward* (@John-Wimpey)
- *Chicken*

Comment: Only your first word fits the situation at all. The others have real meanings that don't fit.

Comment: And I wouldn't really say that a "bully" fears the strong by definition.

Answer (score 1):

There is a humorous word for this: ***dastard*** (not *bastard* but almost)

> A malicious coward; a dishonorable sneak.
>
> <sup>http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dastard</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In politics you might call such a person a 'Chickenhawk'.

Answer (score 0):

This person can be strong and weak at the same time - *coward*.

Comment: Calling someone a "coward" does not reflect him tending to bully the weak.