# Word(s) for a person who degrades other people's work/efforts anonymously

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

Word(s) for a person who degrades other people's work/efforts anonymously.

---

*meta:*
I really want to know since this sickness is wide-spread across Internet.

To me, this is a filthy mix of cowardice and total lack of integrity. One word that is close (too strong, though) is 'terrorist', lowlifes, hiding behind masks or anonymous accounts, disseminating hate. It is interesting whether such a word exists because calling names is so infectious, and the immediate reaction usually is to name back, here lies the trickiness of this non-human act - to drag you in the pit.

Comment: [Troll](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=troll) is the most common for what you describe. Haters as well, but that one is overused.

Comment: Indeed, but I still wonder for existence of specific words outside the Internet jargon, for other spheres of life.

Comment: @medica - Haters gonna Hate!

Comment: This strikes me as primarily a rant. Consider revising it, since your comment above suggests you may be genuinely curious.

Comment: @JimReynolds Revising it! Why? I am both curious and ranty.

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if there's a word for that.

Comment: @JimReynolds In Russian and Bulgarian (which are brother* languages) there are such words, most of them are offensive slang, I do want to describe a situation with correct word without going profane. Jim, just an example, once I encountered such a bad person that everyone was chocked and couldn't utter a word, we were wordless but I went close to him looked in the eye and said 'bezduschen' meaning 'soulless'.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it is a thinly-veiled rant fuelled by the close-votes OP received on another thread in an answer OP started 'I can't help, but ...'. In saying  'To me, this is a filthy mix of cowardice and total lack of integrity' OP is in danger of libelling a regular contributor who, on Meta, and by name, defends his right to anonymously downvote. Though I myself think it helpful to give reasons for downvoting (and sometimes get personal abuse). I sometimes try to explain others' downvotes.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This may not be the word the OP is seeking, but I describe the action of downvoting without explanation a *dastardly deed* - a bit like allowing one's dog to foul the footpath and not clean it up.

Comment: @JimReynolds There is, there is, very glad I am that I found it, you may see my answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Edwin, you're wrong!
If you knew me a bit you would see yourself how defective is your statement:
*"OP is in danger of libelling a regular contributor who..."*  
Don't mess contributing with misgiving/miscontributing, there is nothing helpful in downvoting while not offering a single word why, it is as if looking down on persons who try to understand something, no no it is like spitting on someone's effort while just passing by.

Think it over, I went through a saga full with blackadderish "contributors" until this came out: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/Sanmayce#articles

Comment: If the degradation in question is nothing more virulent than a downvote, then I think _degrades_ is not at all an apt verb. What the downvoter does is assert (by casting the vote) that the question or answer thus downvoted is neither useful to that person nor worthwhile generally. It's unpleasant to receive those votes—and I think that they are unjustified perhaps as frequently as upvotes are—but I don't think that any downvoter is a churl for not explaining his or her downvote. It's simply part of the price of admission to ask questions and to give answers here—that's all.

Comment: When I taught maths, it was considered very poor teaching not to explain errors for all but the most basic slips. But with an 'answer' on ELU which starts off 'I can't help, but ...', what follows is not going to be an answer and certainly will not qualify as an acceptable 'answer' (or the intro should have been deleted by the poster). The 'answerer' _knows_ the reason why the downvoters have downvoted (unless he's not even bothered to read the ELU regulations); he has _given_ the reason.

Comment: @SvenYargs The verb is quite apt, the stupid downvote situation merely serves as an example (more recent) for my search for word(s) describing such people. Sven, you explain things that are obvious, the thing that you miss is the reason for my negative reaction, it has nothing to do with ranking, I couldn't be careless more, it has to do with seeing Jeff asking a hard question and my desire to enrich his search by adding my take with similar 'problem', my main premise is to help people who need help. It is ugly to see the guy underwater and his question endangered of closing.

Comment: @SvenYargs Imho the price of admission should be effort; not bootcamp.

Answer (score 2):

In internet jargon, there is ***keyboard warrior***. These people hide behind their keyboards in total anonymity and show their hatred towards other users in online platforms.

[Urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Keyboard%20Warrior) has a lot of entries for this term but I'm surprised that [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/keyboard-warrior) includes a definition also:

> A person who makes abusive or aggressive posts on the Internet, typically one who conceals their true identity

Comment: Thank you, you are precise, it describes the situation, still I want to know whether in literature or in colloquial usages exists an analogue to the **keyboard warrior**.

The question turns to be more interesting than I thought initially.

The most used word both in Russian and Bulgarian designating a honorless slander hiding himself is 'подлец', with quick cross-references I found one excellent unknown to me word 'DASTARD':
...

Comment: **dastard**
1 obsolete: DULLARD

2 : one who shrinks from danger: COWARD; especially: one who carries out malicious or sneaky acts without exposing himself to danger *like a dastard and a treacherous coward— Shakespeare*
/Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary/

Comment: Also looking into three other dictionaries:
  

dastard - a sneaking, malicious coward.
[Middle English, probably alteration of Old Norse dæstr, exhausted, from past participle of dæsa, to languish, decay.]
/American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition/
  

dastard - a contemptible sneaking coward
[C15 (in the sense: dullard): probably from Old Norse dæstr exhausted, out of breath]
/Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged/

  
dastard - a mean, sneaking coward.
/Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary/

Comment: Reminds me this question: [Word to describe someone who fears the strong but bullies the weak](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205111/word-to-describe-someone-who-fears-the-strong-but-bullies-the-weak/205251#205251). I gave "dastard" as an answer there :)

Comment: Yes, but once more, the main quality which I need described is the anonimity.

I wonder whether 'out of breath' has all to do with **out of soul/anima**:

**anima**: From Latin anima (“a current of air, wind, air, breath, the vital principle, life, soul”).

I mean, whether 'soulless' overlaps with original 'dastard' meaning.

Answer (score 2):

First thanks to all for being helpful, your suggestions triggered (it took 14 hours) in me recollection of one forgotten but lovely BBC serial:
**Blackadder**

*Comedy set in different historical periods that features the ill-fated exploits of the mean-spirited Edmund Blackadder and his dim sidekick Baldrick. Starring Rowan Atkinson.*

Mr. Atkinson is one of my favorite actors, yet, his superb performance didn't pop up at once, perhaps due to my concentration on the present problems, a shame.

For those who didn't watch the series, find time, it is totally worth it.

I believe 'blackadder' is the word I was looking for since it fits almost perfectly, it carries the main features of a 'terrorist' without being so strong:

- venomous attack coming of out nowhere, you know it is one of those repulsive snakes hiding;
- blah-blah, just nasty viper.

Interesting etymology found in Wikipedia:

*The name "adder" is derived from nædre an Old English word that had the generic meaning of serpent in the older forms of many Germanic languages. It was commonly used in the Old English version of the Christian Scriptures for the devil and the serpent in the Book of Genesis.*

Quite well, devil/serpent, as said in the Bible, does this-and-that to you and afterwards says: *'I don't know you'*, this 'covers' the IRRESPONSIBILITY.

Very happy for the precious flashback, finally two words describe the situation:

- dastard;
- blackadder.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest *digital [hatemonger](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hatemonger)* to convey the idea that their activity is mainly carried out through the Internet and possibly anonymously.

> - One who incites others to hatred or prejudice.
> - A person who encourages hatred towards a person or group of people.

Comment: Didn't know that word, thanks, but the accent is on the anonymity and not taking responsibility for one's actions - that is what pisses me off.

Comment: @Georgi'Kaze'- are you familiar with the old saying, "opinions are like ass_____ ? Take a deep breath and shake it off, Georgi.

Comment: @LittleEva Thanks for the ... shake-it-off suggestion, Eva. But this is not my way of dealing with shitty persons, you see I believe that one should confront in a open manner problems and problematic people, saying eye-to-eye what is the problem is half the solution, quite as the old saying about sick people: *"The correct diagnose is half the cure."*
Being **precise in wording** is a very powerful human capability. I want to hear your opinion on my answer of this thread, very glad I am that the sought word popped up.

Answer (score 1):

"**a virtual vandal**" is what I can come up with.

> - vandal - (noun) "a person who deliberately destroys or damages property belonging to others." [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vandal) "a person who vandalizes something" [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vandal)

Although it doesn't include the "hate-spreading" meaning you're looking for, I believe "vandalism" itself generates hatred.

Comment: Thank you, vandalism it is, yes. I just need the combo **sneaky** and **vandal**, in order to discern it from the regular vandals who don't mind doing their ... vandalism without hiding.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Curmudgeon)

**Curmudgeon**: (noun) a crusty, ill-tempered, and usually old man. *my neighbor is a curmudgeon*.

> Synonyms: grouch • grump • grumpy • crab • killjoy • old fart • scrooge • sourpuss •
>   buzzkill • crank • grouse • niggard • angry • cantankerous • cheapskate • complainer •
>   miser • old school • pastry • unhappy

From [Google](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=cur+define&gws_rd=ssl)

> Cur /kər/: (*noun*): cur; *plural noun*: curs
>   an aggressive dog or one that is in poor condition, especially a mongrel.
>   *synonyms*: mongrel, mutt "a mangy cur" •*informal* a contemptible man.

Comment: Thanks, Urban Dictionary many times saved the day, it is a great resource, didn't look there.
These are all very ringy and descriptive but fail to connote/denote the main aspect - being anonymous. Maybe some sister words to HIDEOUS-WHILE-HIDING would do.

Comment: @Georgi'Kaze'- the Looming Lurkers or the Creeping Creeps!